# How do I a Create Shortcut to Shared Network Drive for Computers on Domain without Logging Into Each One Individually

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008

I have a small business with the computers on a domain. I have recently created a shared folder that everyone needs access to (located on the server). Is there a way to create a shortcut to this shared folder on each of the computers in the domain (all at once or individually) without having to sit down at each computer and create a shortcut to the share?

I ask this because the business is an hour drive from me and I have a remote connection to the server, but not to each of the computers on the domain. I have already created a shared folder on the server, but would like the other computers to have access to the shared folder without having to drive out to the business and manually set up access to the share on each of the computers.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the "psexec" command paired with "net use" to map a share to a drive on each computer. You wouldn't have to be there physically to do it, but you would still have to do it one by one. (edit: sorry, I skipped over the part where you said you don't have remote access to all the computers)

Or you can map a shared drive through group policy all in one go. I believe they would have to log out and log back in for it take effect.

The GPO is in `User Configuration > Preferences > Windows Settings > Drive Maps`.

Comment: What I ended up doing was using the C$ secret share to each of the users' computers and copying a manually made shortcut file to each of the desktops. It seems to have worked.

Comment: To elaborate a little you could, with some pre-work hoop-jumping, create a list of computers and create a batch file to run psexec (or a copy command) to place the shortcut link onto the drives of the remote computers.

Answer (score 0):

connect to the server and create a logon script that connects the user when he/she logs on.

I assume you're on a windows domain.  Open Active Directory, user properties, profile tab.  Type the name of your logon script in the field.

The logon script can be a simple batch file:

net use h:  \\servername\shared folder